# How I can make to appear a error message if the user stopping brutal the process?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have a method to install a program:

```
private void Install_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Process process = new Process())
    {    
        // The installer itself 
        process.StartInfo.FileName = ExeFile;
        if (fileArr1.Equals("installer.ini"))
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-if C:\temp\installer.ini";
        if (fileArr1.Equals("installer_input.txt"))
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-if C:\temp\installer_input.txt";
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

How I can make to appear a error message : `" the process was stop "` if the user stopping brutal the process?

Comment: stop, only stop. I don't want to appear the visual-studio message error.

Comment: Are you wondering about how to output an error message, how to get feedback from a `Process`, check if a program has been installed correctly or check if a process has been closed unexpectantly? In its current form, this question is very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If your process has a name, you could check this doing the folowing:

```
if (!Process.GetProcessesByName("process_name").Length > 0)
{
    // Is not running
}
```

Comment: So how do you differentiate if the application was closed normally?

Comment: Good point, but should there be a difference? Isn't it better to cancel and clean the install in one way?

Answer (score -1):

use BackgroundWorker and waitfrom, so user won't stop process

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/160219/ProgressForm-A-simple-form-linked-to-a-BackgroundW